# Creando COMBOBOX con PHP

Tags: php, html, combobox

estoy construyendo un COMBOBOX en mi pagina WEB cuando ejecuto este script de PHP en un archivo independiente trabaja a la mil maravilla retornando todas la opciones que va a tener el combobox. Pero al copiar y pegar el script dentro de la pagina WEB en lugar de llenar el combobox con los valores lo que me trae el cuerpo del PHP que genera los valores y no lo esperado. Que me recomiendas que debo hacer.?

```
$categorias='https://m3ukodi.com/temp/lista.php';
echo '<select name="channel_selector" size="1" id="cha_sele" style="position:absolute;left:22px;top:49px;width:200px;height:28px;z-index:0;" tabindex="2" title="Selecciones un Canal">';


        $re = '/#EXTINF:(.+?)[,]\s?(.+?)[\r\n]+?((?:https?|rtmp):\/\/(?:\S*?\.\S*?)(?:[\s)\[\]{};"\'<]|\.\s|$))/';              
            $input = file_get_contents($categorias);
            preg_match_all($re, $input, $matches);
                     foreach($matches[0] as $list) {
                        preg_match($re, $list, $matchList);
                            echo '<option value="'.trim($matchList[3]).'">'.$matchList[2].'</option>';
                     }
                
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Y esta página web donde colocas el código ¿qué extensión tiene?

Comment: Index.php es decir que es otro PHP

Answer (score 0):

Pero creo que descubri el porque, esta usando ./../../lista.php para recibir la lista y en el php de muestra colocaba http://xxx.com/lista.php por lo que ni el  file_get_contest ni curl lo leian correctamente. Tal vez desde un principio debi usar algun otro comando que viera el PHP local como lo veria en Remoto los comando antes mencionados. Si alguien sabe cual commando debi usar seria bien recibido el dato.